# CPP Client Server Send Failed

Tags: c++, sockets

the program main propose:
reading words from txt file and send server .
i got this eroor:

> socket send failed : Connection reset by peer
>   // rc = send (fd, word, length, 0);

I will give you client.cpp if you want i give server.cpp

```
/*
g++ client.cpp -Wall -g3 -o ozgurtcpclnt
*/

using namespace std;

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "first.h"
#include <vector>

#define TCP_SERVER_PORT 54321
#define BUFFER_LENGTH   1024

const char * message = "selam dostum!";

int main () {
    char word[IO_BUF_LENGTH + 1] = { 0 };

    int length = 0;

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen("combinedText.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen failed");
        return 0;
    }

    char buffer [BUFFER_LENGTH + 1] = {0};
    int fd;
    int rc;
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;

    memset (&s_addr, 0, sizeof (s_addr));

    fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf ("socket failed : %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit (1);
    }

    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    s_addr.sin_port = htons (TCP_SERVER_PORT);

    rc = connect (fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof (s_addr));

    if (rc < 0) {
        printf ("connect failed : %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit (1);
    }
    /*length = strlen(message);
    rc = send (fd, message, length, 0);*/

    while (fscanf(fp, MAX_WORD_SCANF, word) != EOF) {
        length = strlen(word);

        if (length > 1) {
            rc = send (fd, word, length, 0);

            if (rc != length) {
                printf (" socket send failed : %s\n", strerror (errno));
                exit (1);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    length = strlen(word);
    rc = recv (fd, word,length, 0);

    if (rc < 0) {
        printf ("recv failed : %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit (1);
    }

    printf ("Server said : %s\n", word);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good to have some spacing (newlines) between sections of code, but maybe not *that* much?

Comment: As for the error, it seems that the server closed the connection in a bad way, as in it might have crashed or been forcibly closed some other way that prevented it from calling `close` (or the Windows `closesocket`). So you need to look at what happened in the server. A ***guess*** is that you forget to zero-terminate the string you receive from the client leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, it's completely okay for `send` to not send all data at once, TCP is a *streaming* protocol that doesn't have fixed message boundaries. You really need to check what `send` *actually* returns, and only write there was an error if `send` returns `-1`.

Comment: Check out "netcat", which you can use as client and server side replacement. That allows you to test part of your code to circle in on the error.